# UncategorizedSQLException is thrown instead of PessimisticLockingFailureException

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jdbctemplate

I have a list of objects that processing with foreach in a single transaction. For each object I create select for update no wait query. When the the record is already locked I expect to catch PessimisticLockingFailureException, but this exception is thrown only for the first object, for all other objects UncategorizedSQLException is thrown. I don't get what I've done wrong, the code is below.

```
transactionTemplate.execute(tx -> {
    objects(obj -> {
            try {
                SomeEntity entity  =
                        jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                                "select * from table where column = ? for update nowait",
                                mapper,
                                obj.getId()
                        );
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000); // this is just to simulate concurrency and trigger lock
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                ...
            } catch (PessimisticLockingFailureException e) {
                ...
            }
        });
});
```

At first I used JpaRepository for select query, the method was annotated with @Lock, everything was ok, I was catching PessimisticLockingFailureException. Now I need to do the same with JdbcTemplate.

After debugging I found out that the first exception (PessimisticLockingFailureException) is thrown with SQLState 55p03 and UncategorizedSQLException is thrown with SQLState 25p02